# Finding a basis for rational 1 form of a smooth projective curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

Let X be a smooth curve in the projective plane such that for $n \in \mathbb{Z} \geq 2$ we have that $X=Z(-x^n_1+x_0^{n-1}x_2-x^n_2)$. We assume that $n(n-1)$ is in $k^{\times}$. We know that $X$ is smooth and irreducible. We also let $U= Z(f)$ where $f=-y^n=x^{n-1}-1$ Now we have found that 
$$\omega_0= \frac{dx}{ny^{n-1}}=\frac{dy}{(n-1)x^{n-2}}$$ has order $0$ for all points of $U$. And we conclude that $\omega_0$ is a basis for $\Omega^1(U)$ as a free $\mathcal{O}(U)-$module.

We have also calculated that $Q=[1:0:0]$ a unique point at infinity, and that the uniformizer of $U$ is $x_{0,1}$.

We then consider the chain $(x,y) \rightarrow [x:y:1] \rightarrow (y/x, 1/x)$ where $(x,y)=U_2$ and $(y/x, 1/x)=U_0$. We then written $x,y, \omega_0$ usnign the $U_0$ chart, to find $\nu_Q(x)=-n$, $\nu_Q(y)=(1-n)$, and $\nu_Q(\omega_0)=(n-3)n$.

We now want to find a basis for $\Omega^1(X)$ for $n=2,3,4$. I believe that we have $\omega_0$ as a basis for $\Omega^1(X)$ when $n=3$, as the valuation at $Q$ is zero in that case. And I also believe that $Q \in U_0$ so it is also taken care of in this case.

I am however lost on how to find a basis $n=2,4$. I think that the correct route is to find an $\omega_0$ such that $\nu_Q(\omega_0)=0$. But I don't know now how to do this. I am also wondering in general how to think about a basis for $\Omega^1(X)$. I think another route is to find an open cover of $Q$ such that on this open cover intersected with the $U$ defined above the rational one forms agree. But I am also uncertain how to calculate this explicitly, and this argument is dependent on $Q$ being only point from $X$ not in $U$. All the best.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want rational $1$-forms, or regular $1$-forms? The notation $\Omega^1(X)$ usually means the latter. If $X$ has genus $g$ then $\Omega^1(X)$ has dimension $g$ as a vector space over the base field. So when $n = 2$, $\Omega^1(X)$ has dimension $0$ and there are no regular differentials. There is a general formula for a basis of regular differentials of a smooth plane curve: see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/820927/) or [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2726917/holomorphic-1-form-on-projective-curve#comment5628617_2726917).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think we are looking at rational 1-forms.

Comment: The space of rational $1$-forms is $1$-dimensional as a $K(X)$-vector space for any smooth curve $X$. You can take $dx$ (or $d$ of any local coordinate) as a basis.