# Proving non-existence of poles of differential 1-form on zero set in $\mathbb{A}^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-forms

For the differential 1-form $\omega_0=\frac{dx}{ny^{n-1}}=\frac{dy}{(n-1)x^{n-2}}$ ($n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geqslant2}$ and $n(n-1)\in k^*$) I want to show that it doesn't have any poles on $U=Z(f)\subset\mathbb{A}^2$ where $f=x^{n-1}-y^n-1$. Now I guess that the poles are the points $(x,y)\in\mathbb{A}^2$ where either $ny^{n-1}=0$ or $(n-1)x^{n-2}=0$. By this definition there is a pole $(x,y)=(1,0)$, but there shouldn't be any, so certainly I am doing something wrong and the question is: how to fix that?

Comment: How did you get a pole at $(x,y)=(1,0)$?

Comment: @TedShifrin If $y=0$, then $ny^{n-1}=0$ and by the equation of $f$ we get $x=1$.

Comment: But in a neighborhood of the point $(1,0)$ we have $\omega_0 = \frac{dy}{(n-1)x^{n-2}}$ and this is a regular (holomorphic) $1$-form. (The two local expressions for $\omega_0$ are equal because we're restricting to $f=0$. The problem is somewhat confusingly stated.)

Comment: @TedShifrin Okay, so I can simply state that by this function $f$ cannot have both $x$ and $y$ zero and hence there are no poles?

Comment: That's correct. :) Well, I would say it slightly more carefully and say that on $f=0$ we cannot have ... .

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3449159/finding-a-basis-for-rational-1-form-of-a-smooth-projective-curve